# Webpack Sass-loader relative path

Tags: css, webpack, sass, sass-loader

I have an issue where I import font awesome into my main scss file using `@import`. The issue is font awesome _varibles.scss uses a relative path to import its fonts `../fonts/*`. This is causing an error because webpack is trying to load the file relative to the entry point which is the main sass file. I have been trying to use options such as `includePaths` with no luck and loaders like `resolve-url-loader`. I have tried multiple paths but no joy. the main.scss file is located in the sass folder along with a vendor folder that holds the font awesome data.

```
                test: /\.scss$/,
                use: [{
                        loader: "style-loader"
                    },
                    {
                        loader: 'css-loader'
                    },
                    {
                        loader: 'resolve-url-loader'
                    },
                    {
                        loader: 'sass-loader',
                        options: {
                            includePaths: [
                                path.resolve(__dirname, "assets/css/vendor/fontawsome/scss")
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                ]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue isn't related to the fact that you misspelled fontaw**e**some in your path?

> "assets/css/vendor/font**aw**some/scss"